# How do I read the usage information my electrical meter sends to my power company?

Tags: circuit-breaker, power, meter

I would like to keep an eye on what information my power meter sends to my electric company. Is there a way to use, for example, powerline networking to read what usage statistics the power meter sends to my electric company?

Comment: What country are you in?  When I was searching for whole house power monitors for myself, there were different options in different areas of the world.

Comment: If nothing 'modern' will work, you can walk outside to the meter every now and then and check it there. You could keep a record of your usage that way.

Comment: Contact your utility, and ask them if they make the data available.  Trying to swipe the data, could be viewed by the utility as tampering. Accusations of tampering are typically followed by hefty fines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I live in Texas, and there is a public information type site that is maintained by a group called Smart Meters Texas.

[Smart Meter Texas](https://www.smartmetertexas.com/CAP/public/home/home_about_us.html)

On this site you can sign up, register your electric meter, and then see the data from it in 15 minute intervals.  The data is delayed about two days, but it's very informative.

You may search for your area or ask your public utility company if they have something similar.